# Strange (Wrong?) font selection in agency.css?

Tags: css, fonts

I am working on a theme for a new website. We had some professional graphics help us design the theme. For the front page, they took and tweaked the [Agency theme](https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/agency/).

If you download that theme (it is free) and search for the `agency.css` file and open it, there is one CSS line to indicate the default font of the page:

```
body
{
    font-family: "Roboto Slab", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

As we can see, the specified fonts in `font-family` start with *["Roboto Slab"](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto+Slab)*, then it goes on with *["Helvetica Neue"](https://www.fonts.com/font/linotype/neue-helvetica?QueryFontType=Web&src=GoogleWebFonts)*, *["Helvetica"](https://www.fonts.com/font/linotype/helvetica?QueryFontType=Web&src=GoogleWebFonts)*, *["Arial"](https://www.fonts.com/font/monotype/arial?QueryFontType=Web&src=GoogleWebFonts)*, and finally, the default *"sans-serif"* that the browser would be happy about.

Only the *"Roboto Slab"* font is a *"serif"* font, all the others are *"sans-serif"* fonts...

As a designer, would you say that this is a mistake? Because if your computer does not include the font or if the font is somehow not available at the link above, it would go from a *"serif"* font to a *"sans-serif"* font... That seems wrong to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different aspects you should consider:

1. Providing different font families for the same text is no longer needed in modern web.

This is a legacy technique back from when fonts were required to be installed on a machine in order to be used for rendering a web page. Since we now are able to provide fonts as `css` files and load them using `@font-face` declarations, (which I assume your website uses), the fallback only occurs when the machine rendering the website fails at loading the provided font file (this is extremely rare and, when it happens, it is likely that fonts rendering with a different face is not the most serious rendering problem of the page - so the best course of action would probably be to just reload the page).

2. If the second and the third font options were provided by the designer (provided they are professionals) the fonts were probably matched with your other main font and, even though it's part of a different type, it will still complement the other font well.

---

I'd like to point out I actually have design related studies but have turned into a professional coder over the past ~10 years.
Choosing and matching fonts is a complex process and more often than not, the right `size`, `weight` or `style` weigh in more than whether the font is `serif`, `sans-serif`, `monotype` or `fantasy`. There's no recipe for matching fonts and usually it involves taking a step back and looking through dimmed eyes. It's also important one also tests with multiple types and combinations of content, to make sure they all are balanced and look well.

In design, following strict rules gets you above average results, but never in the top `10%`. Those are most times based on bold actions and inspiration. Don't measure the designer's work using a ruler. If you really need to, measure it in terms of user behavior. If there's an increase in traffic/response/commitment, you got a good design.

Comment: Point (2) could be it. There are other `font-family` entries that reference the exact same list of fonts. It's like `font-family: <some-name>, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;` each single time. It still feels somewhat strange to me that you would switch between a `serif` and `sans-serif` but that would explain the _"mistake"_. That would mean that all the fonts would become the same (say `Arial`) if all priors would be missing. Cool.

Comment: @AlexisWilke, I felt my answer needed more detail and I added it. Make sure you're using the right tool at measuring *"design"*. And, IMHO, there's only one proper tool for that: user satisfaction when using your product.

Answer (score 1):

The answer you will get from a question like this will to some degree be based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise. My opinion is that all important browsers support web fonts. If the web font is used correctly it will show correctly to 99.9% of the site visitors. The other fonts listed is just fallbacks for the 0.1% visitors that for some reason is not able to load the custom web font. The most important thing is that they will be able to read your content. If you would like to control the fallback font, you should choose a set of system native fonts present on all platforms. You could use courier, but that is a mono spaced font (fixed-width) and I doubt it is more readable or fancy. A sans serif is also more modern than e.g. Times and therefore closer to the modern look of Roboto Slab.

Comment: What about listing just "Roboto Slab" and "serif", instead of 4 other types of fonts that are "sans-serif"? Wouldn't that at least makde more sense?

Comment: Lots of corrections – it is late in my part of the world (midnight) and English is not my native language. Some percentage may also not see the webfont correctly because they are so tired :-D Helvetica is primarily for Mac and iOS where these fonts are native. Some would say that helvetica is more elegant than Sans serif. Others would say that it does not matter as long as it is readable for the 0.1% or so users.

Comment: "Sans Serif" is (also) a name of a widely used font. "Serif" is not (as far as I know). At least it is not shipped with OS X, iOS or Windows, I think. You will have to look for others (like Times): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_typefaces_included_with_Microsoft_Windows https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_typefaces_included_with_macOS